Rigid Body Issue: Pencil does not rotate during fall, keeps original rotation
I'm new to these forums so please let me know if I need to do something differently.
I'm trying to drop this pencil (in the future, multiple pencils) in a box, like a desk organiser.
I've turned on rigid bodies for both the pencil and the box (the pencil is Active, the box is Passive).

The pencil falls into the box as expected, but doesn't tilt sideways to lean against the side, it stays in the exact same rotation as it was originally.

I'm at a loss at for what to change, I've set the origin to geometry, I've also tried setting it to the centre of mass....


Blend file:

Thanks in advance for your help! 

Hi Kattcrazy, welcome!  To upload a blend file, start here.  Also further guidance on what to include, if it's not obvious, here.   Now that I know how, the only thing I need to remember is "blend-" which autocompletes to "blend-exchange.com" in my browser.

yes please share your file

@DonHatch thanks for the link, I'm waiting for the .blend to upload now :)

@moonboots https://blend-exchange.com/b/bBAgp6Vy here is the file

@Kattcrazy You can already apply scale on both objects Ctrl+A > Scale. Your objects will go crazy, maybe try adding damping or more subframe (I don't really know).

@Kattcrazy Also change the pencil collision shape to Convex which is enough + increase friction on both objects. Animation looks ok for me with these changes.

Try this :

Apply the scale of both the pen and the box
For the pen choose Shape > Convex Hull
Set both the pen and box Surface Response > Friction to 1
Set their Sensitivity > Margin to 0


Thank you so much, it works now!

Little mistake, I meant set the margin to 0 (to have no distance between the pen and box)

https://summersketches.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/Group-Render.jpg
Here's final result  link is to the image on my website since I couldn't figure out how to add images to a comment

Oh ok you have a lot of pens, I understand now why you wanted to use physics   ;)

@Kattcrazy to add images to a comment, the trick I use is: pretend to start to write an Answer to any random question in a separate browser tab; insert an image into it; that will upload your image, and the image url beginning with https://i.sstatic.net/ will appear somewhere in your pretend-answer; copy-paste that into the comment where you want it, and abort the pretend-answer (just close the browser tab).  I don't know whether there's an easier way.
